# Having trouble with user.is_authenticated in django template

Tags: django, authentication

Sorry if you tried helping me when I asked this earlier. Had to delete that question because I wasn't being allowed to edit additional information for some reason.

I'm working on implementing user authentication on my django website. Everything works. My views, models, urls, etc. are all set up. Users can register, log in, log out. The issue I'm having is with this bit of code:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
      <li><a href="/logout">Log Out</a></li>
      {% else %}
      <li><a href="/login">Log In</a></li>
      {% endif %}
```

Even when I'm logged in, it is still displaying "Log In" as an option rather than "Log Out". However, if I click on the link, it'll redirect me to /profile because that's what the view tells it to do if I'm logged in. So, clearly it knows I'm logged in, but the template isn't readint user.is_authenticated as true.

The view relating to login requests is:

```
def LoginRequest(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            profile = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if profile is not None:
                login(request, profile)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
            else:
                return render_to_response('template/login.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        else:
            return render_to_response('template/login.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        ''' user is not submitting the form, show them login form ''' 
        form = LoginForm()
        context = {'form': form}
        return render_to_response('template/login.html', context, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If the auth context processor is enabled, then `user` is already in the template context, and you can do:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
```

If you want to access `request` in the template, make sure you have enabled the [request context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/api/#django-template-context-processors-request).

In your question you are using `render_to_response`. Ever since Django 1.3, it has been better to use `render` instead of `render_to_response`. Using `render_to_response` with `RequestContext(request)` works in Django <= 1.9, but from Django 1.10 onwards you must use the `render` shortcut if you want the context processors to work.

```
return render(request, 'template/login.html', context)
```

Comment: My template context processors are

("django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
"django.core.context_processors.debug",
"django.core.context_processors.i18n",
"django.core.context_processors.media",
"django.core.context_processors.static",
"django.core.context_processors.tz",
"django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages")

what's the path to the request one?

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize I left request.user.is_authenticated in there. I tried adding it cause I thought it would help, but it didn't. The template doesn't work with or without "request." there

Comment: For the view where the logout link not displaying correctly, make sure you are rendering the template with a `RequestContext`

Comment: The debug toolbar is useful for troubleshooting problems like these, as it can show you the template context.

Comment: thank you Alasdair. I was using render_to_response which doesn't include a RequestContext object. That's why I was unable to access the user in my template. your comment led me to the solution :) I'm using render() now instead, which is exactly the difference to render_to_response: it adds a RequestContext

Comment: @user3182532 good point - this answer was written a long time ago when it was still ok to use `render_to_response`, but I've updated it to say that you must use `render` from Django 1.10 onwards.

Answer (score 7):

Be aware that since Django **1.10** the `is_authenticated` is decorated with **@property** and it behaviour differs.

For **UNAUTHENTICATED** user calling {{user.is_authenticated}} results:

`CallableBool(True)` (when on Django < 1.10 it was `True`)

For **AUTHENTICATED** user calling {{user.is_authenticated}} results:

`CallableBool(False)` (when on Django < 1.10 it was `False`)

If you need to pass e.g to your javascript value like `true` or `false`you can do it with applying filter `|yesno:"true,false"`

```
<script language="javascript"> 
var DJANGO_USER = "{{user.is_authenticated|yesno:"true,false"}}";
</script>
```