# how to use django authentication in "main" template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I've created a main HTML file where I have a template for all apps.

And in every other template file I am using :

```
{% extends "main.html" %}
```

To get the content.

But there are things I want to add to the main template but only if user is authenticated.

I know I can use

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
```

but it doesn't work in main.html file.

Do you know what am I doing wrong ?
What should I do to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Having trouble with user.is\_authenticated in django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17032174/having-trouble-with-user-is-authenticated-in-django-template)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Use {% debug %} template tag to understand User.
 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#debug

Or
2) Using  {% request.user.is_authenticated %} should get the authenticated user information from the Http Request.

Comment: hey , changed it, but receiving following error "Invalid block tag on line 15: 'request.user.is_authenticated'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?"

Comment: Doru is right. If you still facing the problem its better to provide a snippet of the view and the template.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %} 
    your code here 
{% endif %}
```