# request.user.is_authenticated working only in the home page

Tags: python, django, authentication

I am creating a website where a user can upload documents. If user is logged out he can view other's document but not download it 
if user is logged in he can download the document from the toolbar in pdf viewer

Even when I am logged out request.user.is_authenticated is false in home page but its true in other pages. So the download button does not hide nor a login button shows up.

I have tried using user.is_authenticated but it was returning true all the time

the if else condition works fine in the index page but not in doc_detail.html

urls.py

```py
re_path(r'^all_files/(?P<doc_id>[0-9]+)/$',views.doc_detail,name = 'doc_detail'),
path('login/',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='homework/login.html'),name = 'login'),
```

views.py

```py
def doc_detail(request,doc_id):
    template = loader.get_template('homework/doc_detail.html')
    doc = get_object_or_404(Document, pk = doc_id)
    context = {
    'doc':doc
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context,request))
```

doc_detail.html

```html
{{ doc.user.username }}
{{ doc.title }}
{{ doc.doc_type }} <br>

{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <iframe src="{{ doc.document.url }}#toolbar=1&navpanes=0&scrollbar=1" type="application/pdf" width = "80%" height = "600px" />
{% else %}
    <iframe src="{{ doc.document.url }}#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" type="application/pdf" width = "80%" height = "600px"  />
    <a href=" url 'homework:login'">login</a>
{% endif %}
```

index page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
This is the homework page implement upload-routine explore-routine here  
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %} 
the user is {{ request.user.email }} {{ request.user.profile.institution }}

{% else %}
user not logged in
{% endif %}

{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <a href="{% url 'homework:logout' %}">logout</a>
    <a href="{% url 'homework:update' %}">update</a>
    <a href="{% url 'homework:upload' %}">upload</a>
    <a href="{% url 'homework:my_uploads' %}">my uploads</a><br>
{% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'homework:login' %}">login</a><br>
{% endif %}

<a href="{% url 'homework:all_files' %}">all files</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#users

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Having trouble with user.is\_authenticated in django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17032174/having-trouble-with-user-is-authenticated-in-django-template)

Comment: But my code is using render instead of render_to_response @ivan and the docs provided by you is already tried and its working for me in home page 
I will include the template for the home page in the question

Comment: Please take another look at the docs and compare the sample code with yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you should be using the render shortcut; it seems you are confusing that with the render method of a template. There's no reason to be using the template object directly here, or just about anywhere in standard Django code.

```
def doc_detail(request, doc_id):
    doc = get_object_or_404(Document, pk=doc_id)
    context = {
        'doc':doc
    }
    return render(request, 'homework/doc_detail.html', context)
```

Comment: I have tried this code but still it isn't working
but now I have observed that if I check the user.is_authenticated in view function it works fine but not in the rendered template
def all_files(request):
 template = 'homework/all_files.html'
 docs = Document.objects.all()
 context = {
 'docs': docs,
 }
 # if request.user.is_active:
 #  print(request.user)
 if(request.user.is_authenticated):
  return render(request = request,template_name = template,context = context)
 else:
  return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('homework:index'))
this works as required but problem comes in templ.

Comment: Do you have `'django.template.context_processors.request'` in your templates context_processors setting? Show that setting.

Answer (score 0):

views.py

```
@login_required
def doc_detail(request,doc_id):
    template = loader.get_template('homework/doc_detail.html')
    doc = get_object_or_404(Document, pk = doc_id)
    context = {
    'doc':doc
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context,request))
```

doc_detail.html

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <iframe src="{{ doc.document.url }}#toolbar=1&navpanes=0&scrollbar=1" type="application/pdf" width = "80%" height = "600px" />
{% else %}
    <iframe src="{{ doc.document.url }}#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" type="application/pdf" width = "80%" height = "600px"  />
    <a href=" url 'homework:login'">login</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: The point is that doc_detail view should be accessible to non-logged users but specific contents should be hidden. @login_required will make them create new account and login even if they are just visiting the website for exploring the pages

Comment: You try only `user.is_authenticated`

Comment: still no luck :(