# my user authentification is not working only shows Logout link, else statement doesnt work

Tags: python, django

I cant get this to work. I am trying to authenticate users logged in but it only shows the log out link when logged in and when logged out. I am thinking theres something wrong with the else statement, I am doing this on django:

````
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-steel fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand mr-4" href="{% url 'blog-about' %}">Django Blog</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggle" aria-controls="navbarToggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggle">
            <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'blog-home' %}">Home</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'blog-about' %}">About</a>
            </div>
    <!-- Navbar Right Side -->
            <div class="navbar-nav">
              {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
              {% else %}
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
              {% endif %}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav> ```
````

Comment: You probably want to use “request.user” instead of “user”

Comment: can you show us how you render the template?

Comment: You are most likely missing a `RequestContext` in your render call

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Having trouble with user.is\_authenticated in django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17032174/having-trouble-with-user-is-authenticated-in-django-template)

Comment: fixed it guys there was a issue with my urls.py file where I had not updated the logout view path: ```path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout'),```